# Why does my wireless router disconnect when I turn on my cellphone's WiFi?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, connection

For the last seven months, I have been dealing with Internet problems. However I finally found out why my wireless router has been disconnecting randomly.

Every time I enable WiFi on my HTC Android cellphone, the whole router disconnects and I lose Internet until I switch the WiFi off on my phone.

I don't understand why it is doing this – has this happened to you? How can I fix it?

Comment: Interesting, what router is it?  I know of a similar case with an HTC Desire HD, and a D-Link router I believe.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading the firmware of the router?

Comment: Hmm, I havent tried that its a AT&T 2WIRE [2701HG-B Gateway] and when I click "View available upgrades and options" It just says page can't be displayed?

Comment: Note that simply connecting a wifi client to a wifi router should never be enough to stop the router working.  This is definitely a bug with the router even if the HTC client is messed up.  If you can't find a firmware fix on the Pace/2Wire website then you might want to consider replacing it.

Comment: Does your phone have a mobile wifi hotspot feature enabled?

Comment: I know this is old and has recently been brought to the top, but check to make sure it's not assigning an IP address to your phone which is already in use for another device. This may cause the two devices to be unable to access the internet properly.

Comment: Thought I'd chime in with a new weird case -- the Android Auto / Apple Carplay wifi in my wife's car stereo (Pioneer AVH-4400NEX) knocks out our router every time she starts her Jeep to leave for work...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, my wife's Samsung S4 was taking down the network. Several other devices connected without issue including my cell phone, but for some reason her phone crashed the network when she turned Wi-Fi on and connected to the network. We tried many things which did not work, and in our case the solution was to create a Guest Zone on the router to which she connected with her Samsung S4.

Comment: Thanks this solves my issue!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is having this issue, **I recommend checking out this post**, specifically the answer by **Raven** (Nov 26, 2018 at 11:57 AM) which covers ADSL, Dial-Up, and WiFi only going down: https://ccm.net/forum/affich-19259-router-disconects-when-phone-gets-used

It seems like a significant number of people (Raven and our very own @chriss included) have said that it's because the phone is on the same channel as the router. While it is true that this ***should not be the case*** as routers can and should be able to handle devices on the same/close channels without anything but minor performance hits, it seems that smartphones are sometimes an exception.

In fact, I also had this issue and I used a WiFi analyzer tool to find a channel that worked better and that solved my problem back in 2018 at my old place.

Note that this may have been a symptom and not the issues. It's possible that the channel was having issues by itself and my smartphone was just the last straw that cuased the network to fail. Either way, changing the channel did fix it.

**Another experience I had** more recently presented similar issues but was rooted from a different issue. Whenever I got home, internet would go out. In this case, even wired devices went out so it was not related to the channel. It turned out that the coaxal connection had issues with it and there was a filter in the line outside that comcast had thrown in as a temporary fix and forgotten about it. After a storm knocked out power and internet, they rediscovered the issue and fixed it, resulting in the problem being solved.

Not sure which it is for you (or anyone else having this issue and coming here), but I recommend having your ISP come test your coaxal connection. Honestly I recommend everyone do this every decade or so and when moving into a new place.

Answer (score 0):

Your cell phone is probably broadcasting on the same channel as your wireless network. The problem could possibly be fixed by changing the channel on your wireless router.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Having 2 devices broadcasting on the same channel should not be enough to cause a problem - indeed this is a very common occurrence, particularly when people setting up wifi devices are unfamiliar with the frequencies other devices in the same area are on, or when there are more WIFI devices then distinct channels (which I've seen)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with a new Netgear WNR2000v5.  Turn on wi-fi on my Galaxy S7 and connect to wi-fi network, no internet, wired and wireless.  Turn off wi-fi on the S7, all other devices work.

To solve this, I enabled guest network.  Now the S7 is the only device connected to the guest wi-fi network.  Everything is working now.